# Rails: Allow users to upvote only once a pin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vote, pins

I have an upvote system in my rails app that allow users to upvote a Pin.
But I would like to restrict the ability to upvote only once a Pin.

**app/controllers/pins_controller.rb**

```
  def upvote
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    @pin.votes.create
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  end
```

**app/models/pin.rb**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

    end
```

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
  resources :pins do
  member do
    post 'upvote'
  end
end
```

I am not sure how to implement that as I tried to implement a system that allowed users to upvote only once, it's not what I want, I want them to be able to upvote a "PIN" only once.
I know that the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem provide this feature, but since I am not using it, I wanted to know if there is a way to implement that on my own code.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: this method only allow one vote per pins. see @Ege solution**

get it to works with this:

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.count == 0
     @pin.votes.create
     redirect_to(pins_path)
  else flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvote this!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You selected beautifulcoder's answer as the correct one, but you should be aware that it is potentially incorrect and it may not be obvious if you're new to Rails.

You say a Pin should only have one vote, but presumably what you mean is that it should have one vote *per user*, as in, each user should be able to upvote a Pin only once. This is how voting mechanisms typically work.

With beautifulcoder's answer, if I upvote a Pin, you will not be able to upvote it, because your controller will count the number of votes on the Pin, return 1 (because I upvoted it) and prevent you from upvoting. Furthermore, it will flash a message saying you have upvoted it, whereas you haven't!

How to solve this problem? Fortunately, Rails makes this super easy. Your Vote is actually a Join Model in disguise. It establishes a relationship (i.e. association) between users and pins. A user can upvote a pin, and a pin can be upvoted by a user. In other words, votes "connect" users and pins! What you need to do is define this relationship by leveraging [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Your Pin model would have this association added:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_users, through: :votes, source: :user

  ...

end
```

This allows you to do stuff like `@pin.upvoted_users` and get a list of users who have upvoted that pin. Pretty nice if you want to be able to notify the pin owner!

You also want to add a reverse association to your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin

  ...

end
```

And then change the Vote model like this:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pin
  validates_uniqueness_of :pin_id, scope: :user_id

end
```

And finally in your controller, you would do:

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    flash[:notice] =  "Thank you for upvoting!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  else 
    flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvoted this!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  end
end
```

Voila! You now have a solution where users can upvote items, but only once per item.

Comment: Hello @Ege I really appreciate your answer, it's really kind of you. The things is that with your method when I tried to upvote a pin i run to an error: unknown attribute: user_id

Comment: If your vote model does not have a user_id integer, you need to add that with a migration. This makes sense if you think about it: Votes belong to users, and therefore their model should have a user_id foreign key.

Comment: This is the right answer. I would create a vote method on the User model and call current_user.vote(@pin) to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Ege Thanks I added a user_id integer to my votes column and now it's working well. The only issue is with the flash message - when i upvote many time, the upvote are accepted only once which is what I want - but the flash message remain the same, even if it's not upvoting because a user already did it, he got the flash message: "thanks for upvoting"

Answer (score 0):

small update to the controller action conditional

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)

  if @pin.save
    flash[:notice] =  "Thank you for upvoting!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  else 
    flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvoted this!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  end
end
```